# Can I use fpcalc to prove two audio files produce the same sound?

Tags: audio, fingerprint-recognition

I'm using fingerprinting techniques to detect duplicate audio files on my music library.

The first and easy step is to compare the file-size and if they match I use a md5 sum to compare them.

The problem is sometimes the meta-tags of an audio file have been modified. So I compare the length (in seconds) of the file and if they match I use fpcalc to compare them.

When I finally have two audio files with different md5 sums but the same result of fpcalc I use picard (musicbrainz) to normalize the meta-tags (removing any tag that isn't a "standard" tag). Sometimes after saving the audio files they become identical but sometimes they are just different.

- Can I use fpcalc to tell that two files have the same audio with the same quality?
- If not, are there any other tools to compare audio files?

I made a small script to make all this easier https://github.com/falkartis/duplicates

If you think I'm doing it wrong can you please tell me.

In my collection I have lots of different file-types like wav, flac, ogg, mp3, wma...

Comment: What is fpcalc?

Comment: It's a command line tool to make an acoustic fingerprint of an audio file. Musicbrainz/Picard uses it to fingerprint audio files and lookup the correct tags for the track. It's like shazam or soundhound.
Should I add this to my question?

Comment: yes, you should. You see, this website is a bit about signal processing as in "we're the ones that do the signal processing library, not the ones that use that library"; so maybe we can help you, but every bit of knowledge about the algorithm employed by `fpcalc` would surely help. I don't think anyone of us has used it, and frankly looking up what algorithms it uses so we can answer your question might be a bit much to ask.

Comment: I see, maybe I'm asking at the wrong place. I tried to understand the algorithm myself, but I'm not smart enough (yet) that's why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fingerprint software (A front-end to the chroma library). It's intended to recognize which song, not quality. If you want to compare the quality then I don't know any way to recognize true quality, but my suggestion would be to move on to extract information using ffprobe, so you can see sample-rate, bit-rate, bit-depth and n:o channels.Unfortunately this won't tell if one file may come from a low quality source recorded in a high bitrate.

I haven't used it so I don't know how accurate it is. I don't think it makes false positives, but would it matter if there is a loud noise in the beginning or end of a file? or different lengths of silence at the beginning or end? Since chroma is used a lot by many different tools I'd expect it to be "useful enough". The nature of identifying things that aren't automatically "identical" is by it's nature something that will have SOME boundary issues.